# Merge view templates in cakephp

Tags: php, templates, cakephp, view

I have 2 templates, 
 - /view/opinions/add.ctp - add form
 - /view/opinions/list.ctp - displays opinions

and I want them diplay in /views/opinions/index.ctp is it possible?

Is the only way to do it by $this -> element() ? if so, can I include templates from /view/opinions instead of /view/elements ?

@edit

OpinionsController.php

```
class OpinionsController extends AppController { 
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

    var $name = 'Opinions'; 

    function index() { 
        $opinions = $this->Opinion->find('all'); 
        if(isset($this->params['requested'])) { 
             return $opinions; 
        } 
        $this->set('opinions', $opinions);       
    } 



    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Opinion->create();
            if ($this->Opinion->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('saved.'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

index.ctp

```
$this->extend('/Opinions/view');
$this->extend('/Opinions/add');
```

add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('Opinion', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('author_name', array('label' => 'Imię'));
echo $this->Form->input('author_signature', array('label' => 'Podpis'));
echo $this->Form->input('text', array('rows' => '5', 'cols' => '30', 'label' => 'Opinia'));
echo $this->Form->input('author_pic', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => 'Zdjęcie')); 
echo $this->Form->input('author_pic_dir', array('type' => 'hidden')); 
echo $this->Form->end('Dodaj opinię');
```

view.ctp 
`

```
<?php foreach ($opinions as $opinion): ?>

    <div class="opinion">
        <div class="author">
            <div class="pic"><?php echo $this->Html->image("defaultAvatar.jpg", array('alt' => $opinion['Opinion']['author_name'])); ?></div>
            <div class="signature"><b><?= $opinion['Opinion']['author_name']?></b><br><i><?= $opinion['Opinion']['author_signature']?></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <blockquote><p><?= $opinion['Opinion']['text']?></p></blockquote>       
        </div>
        <div class="clear"><!-- . --></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"><!-- . --></div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($post); ?>
```

`

Comment: we can do it, just add ur both view code in index.ctp file..  and in index action of ur controller. add ur logic for add and list the values..!!

Answer (score 0):

In web frameworks like CakePHP, we want to keep our code DRY. In order to do what you want, I think the better approach is to create elements to list your opinions and another with the form to add a new one.

Then in `index.ctp` you would put these two elements. And in `add.ctp` you put only the element with the form and in `view.ctp` you should put the element that list the opinions.